# Create hollow cylinder with LibGDX

Tags: java, android, 3d, libgdx

I'm trying to create a hollow cylinder on android application with LibGDX. Looks like there isn't any method that would create it. I tought of drawing two cylinders. One bigger and a smaller one with which I could "remove" the inside of the bigger one therefor creating a hollow cylinder. Now what I'm asking, is there any better way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer #1**

There are two ways to do this. The first is using [createCylinder() convenience method of ModelBuilder](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g3d/utils/ModelBuilder.html#createCylinder%28float,%20float,%20float,%20int,%20int,%20com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.Material,%20long%29) to create a model with a single cylinder mesh in it.

**Answer #2**

Using the [createCylinder()](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g3d/utils/ModelBuilder.html#createCylinder%28float,%20float,%20float,%20int,%20int,%20com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.Material,%20long%29) method of the MeshBuilder class to create a Mesh and then wrap that in a model later.

**Example (way #2)**

The following example code was adapted from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21670740/merging-models-from-modelbuilder-in-libgdx):

```
    MeshBuilder meb = new MeshBuilder();
    final long atr = Usage.Position | Usage.Color; //Add  Usage.TextureCoordinates or similar here if you need it

    //Create mesh #1
    meb.begin(atr);
    meb.cylinder(4f, 6f, 4f, 16);
    Mesh cyl1 = meb.end();

    //Create mesh #2
    meb.begin(atr);
    meb.cylinder(4f, 6f, 4f, 16);
    Mesh cyl2 = meb.end();

    //Combine the two meshes into one model using ModelBuilder
    ModelBuilder mob = new ModelBuilder();
    mob.begin();
    mob.part("cylinder1", cyl1, Usage.Position | Usage.Normal | Usage.TextureCoordinates, new Material(ColorAttribute.createDiffuse(Color.RED), ColorAttribute.createSpecular(1, 1, 1, 1), FloatAttribute.createShininess(8f)));
    mob.part("cylinder2", cyl2, Usage.Position | Usage.Normal | Usage.TextureCoordinates, new Material(ColorAttribute.createDiffuse(Color.GREEN), ColorAttribute.createSpecular(1, 1, 1, 1), FloatAttribute.createShininess(8f))).mesh.transform(new Matrix4().translate(0, 0, -2f));
    Model cyl = mob.end();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make a obj using blender 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JFdVRdD9VSM

Don't forget to triangulate it.

and load using

http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/assets/loaders/ModelLoader.html [included only in nightlies]

you can find a pretty good example in gdx-test repository
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/tree/master/tests/gdx-tests